# Pentaho Report - Xaction file with multiple condition parameters

Tags: report, pentaho, xaction

I am using pentaho 2.x report server,

The report is having a radio button element and two drop down elements in a html page which will be passed to my xaction as parameters,
for now different sqls will be executed based on the radio button value passed to my xaction.

But now i need to check the value of a drop-down and using both radio button and drop down values sqls will be executed.

following is the condition i am using,

`<condition><![CDATA[REPORT=='ACTUAL']]></condition>`

REPORT --> radio button value from html

Need to use another value/pass another parameter to the `<condition>` attribute.

Comment: Not clear what question it is about. Values chosen in drop down combo box, can be used in SQL component is not it?

Comment: You r right martin, but i need to use those values in the <condition> tag of the xaction file, I need to execute different sqls for different drop down values been selected.  For Example  If the REPORT value is ACTUAL and another parameter for example TYPE is equal to NEW -- SQL1 should be executed.  If the REPORT value is ACTUAL and another parameter for example TYPE is equal to OLD -- SQL2 should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <actions> 
    <condition><![CDATA[REPORT.equalsIgnoreCase("ACTUAL") && TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("NEW")]]></condition>
    <action-definition> 
    .... whatever action ... 
    </action-definition> 
  </actions>

  <actions> 
    <condition><![CDATA[REPORT.equalsIgnoreCase("ACTUAL") && TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("OLD")]]></condition>
    <action-definition> 
    .... whatever action ... 
    </action-definition> 
  </actions>
```